# react-router-dom v6 useRoutes error: "No routes matched location "/profile"" when conditionally using protected routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Essentially what the title says i have a `public.js` and `protected.js` routes files and in the index file i call the useRoutes hook on either the public or protected routes depending if the user is logged in or not. it works fine and also the components render for the Profile and Dashboard routes. however i get an error saying `no matched routes for '/xyz'` in the console. this doesn't occur on the public routes but does once i sign in and hit the private routes? any ideas on what could be wrong thank you.

the `AppRoutes` in the `index.js` file is what is exported then used in the BrowserRouter.

```
//public.js

import { Login } from "@/features/auth/routes/Login";
import { Register } from "@/features/auth/routes/Register";

export const publicRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/auth/login',
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: '/auth/register',
    element: <Register />,
  },
];
```

```
//protected.js

import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Profile } from '@/features/users';
import { Dashboard } from '@/features/misc';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Protected Routes View</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

export const protectedRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      { path: '/profile', element: <Profile /> },
      { path: '/dash', element: <Dashboard /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="." /> },
    ],
  },
];
```

```
///index.js

import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';

import { protectedRoutes } from './protected';
import { publicRoutes } from './public';
import { useAuth } from '@/lib/auth';

export const AppRoutes = () => {
  const auth = useAuth()
  
  const routes = auth.user ? protectedRoutes : publicRoutes;

  const element = useRoutes([...routes])

  return <>{element}</>;
};
```

if don't do `const routes = auth.user ? protectedRoutes : publicRoutes;` and instead hard code it as `const routes = protectedRoutes;` it seems to work fine but not sure what the actual cause is to fix it without removing the required conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Don't conditionally render your routes. The issue is that some routes aren't currently mounted and rendered when attempting to navigate to them, so there are times when there ***aren't*** any matched routes for the current URL path.

Create a routes configuration where all routes are rendered unconditionally. Create a protected route for the routes you want to protect. The idea here is to have all the potentially reachable routes mounted at all times.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Login } from "@/features/auth/routes/Login";
import { Register } from "@/features/auth/routes/Register";
import { Profile } from '@/features/users';
import { Dashboard } from '@/features/misc';
import { useAuth } from '@/lib/auth';

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();

  return auth.user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Home />,
  },
  {
    path: '/auth/login',
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: '/auth/register',
    element: <Register />,
  },
  {
    element: <PrivateRoutes />,
    children: [
      { path: '/profile', element: <Profile /> },
      { path: '/dash', element: <Dashboard /> },
    ],
  }
  { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/" replace /> },
];
```

index.js

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { routes } from './routes';

export const AppRoutes = () => {
  const element = useRoutes(routes);

  return element;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are building your project based on bulletproof-react repo because you have exact same code structure to render protected routes. In my case, useQuery doesn't update initialData on mount, so i wrap the useQuery with my own hook.

```
export const useAuth = () => {
  const { data , error, refetch, status, isLoading, fetchStatus, isFetching, isError, isFetched, remove, isStale } = useUser({
    // I don't use initialData, useQuery always returns initialData on mount and gets the data only on tab focus!
    useErrorBoundary: true,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: true,
    refetchOnMount : true,
    retry: 1,
    // should be refetched in the background every 8 hours
    staleTime: 1000,
  });
  const isAuthenticated = data !== null && data !== undefined && data?.email;

  const [ auth, setAuth ] = useState<AuthUser>(initialState)
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(isAuthenticated){
      setAuth({
        id : data.id,
        email : data.email,
        name : data.name,
        authenticated : true
      })
    }else{
      setAuth(initialState);
    }
  }, [ data ])
  console.log(data,error,status,fetchStatus);

  return {
    auth, 
    error, 
    refetch, 
    status, 
    fetchStatus, 
    isLoading, 
    isFetching, 
    isError, 
    isFetched , 
    remove,
    isAuthenticated,
    isStale
  }
}
```

You can check out on my repo https://github.com/galih56/manpro-v2

With this hook, i still able to use the same code you have